# Kotlin's support for spring, questions about nullability

Tags: spring, kotlin

[image]
How do you understand that general type parameters, variable parameters, and array element nullability are not supported? Is there an example to support it? What kind of writing will not be supported?

"For kotlin versions 1.1+, the default behavior is the same as -Xjsr305=warn. The strict value is required to have Spring Framework API null-safety taken into account in Kotlin types inferred from Spring API but should be used with the knowledge that Spring API nullability declaration could evolve even between minor releases and that more checks may be added in the future."I don't quite understand the evolution of controllability declarations between minor versions, what is the evolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when calling Java-defined functions from Kotlin, the nullability of parameters, generic types, and return types cannot be determined, since Java does not provide a standard way to declare nullability.

For this kind of situation, Kotlin has the maybe-nullable type, which is denoted by a `!` instead of `?` after the type name. You can't use this in your own code, but the IDE will show it to you as the type returned by a Java function. For instance, if you call some Java-defined function like this:

```
val x = someJavaBasedApi.fetchSomeString()
```

then Kotlin doesn't know if x is a `String` or `String?`, so it treats it as `String!`. This is effectively the same as `String` except that it won't do an immediate runtime check to make sure it's not null, and the compiler won't complain if you check if it's null to be safe. If you assign it to non-nullable variable but it's actually null, you'll trigger a NullPointerException crash.

Spring evidently uses some annotations to make it so Kotlin **can** detect this nullability in most cases, but not in the three situations described.

Possible example regarding generic types:

```
val x = someSpringApi.fetchAList<String>()
```

You are using the non-nullable `String` type for the kind of list you want to fetch. So you might expect it to return a `List<String>`, but it is actually a `List<String!>`. If you do this, you could have a crash:

```
val x = someSpringApi.fetchAList<String>()
val y: String = x[0]  // possibly assigning null to a non-nullable variable
```

And for arrays, the same thing could happen, where it returns an `Array<String!>`, not an `Array<String>`.

I can't think of an example regarding `varargs` because I don't know how Spring uses them.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer, I don't have enough reputation to vote. If possible, can you add the official website documentation (such as the ! symbol you mentioned)?

Comment: It’s explained [here in the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types). 

If this answered your question, you can mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark, regardless of your reputation.